# Stored image on database as bytes does not show as image on table but as bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, image, arrays

I am trying to save an image to my database in byte array format, but when I look at the database I only see the bytes but not the image! How can I make it so I do not see the byte code but the image? Do I have to reverse the process on client side?
Please help! Thank you!

Byte conversion function:

```
private byte[] String_To_Bytes2(string strInput)
        {
            int numBytes = (strInput.Length) / 2;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];
            for (int x = 0; x < numBytes; ++x)
            {
                bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(strInput.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

Comment: The best solution will be, store image in root folder and save image name in database, that will help you in coding.

Comment: thing is that i need to store it on the database because this will not be a local software

Comment: There's no such notion as image in a database. An image is an array of bytes and databases have column types allowing to store those arrays. I don't know what image do you expect to see.

Comment: interesting that you say that since SQL has image type....

Comment: And where do you expect to see this image?

Comment: Are you displaying it somewhere in your application after retrieving it from the database?

Comment: yes i want to see it in a table in view! As you can see from the code above the image is stored as a byte array! The problem is that after i store it i still see it as a byte array and not as a picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using the first solution found on the following post: 
[Displaying database image (bytes[]) in Razor/MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474822/displaying-database-image-bytes-in-razor-mvc3)

Model.Content is a byte[] image.

```
@{
    string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Content);
    string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);}  <img src="@imageSrc" alt="@Model.Name" width="100" height="100" />
```